# django - class in ChoiceField

Tags: python, django, forms, choicefield

Is there any option to do something like this:
- I have a class:

```
class HumanModel():
    def __init__(self, name=None):
        self.name = name
...

class OtherHumanModel():
    def __init__(self, name=None):
        self.name = name
...
```

etc.

and I have a form:

```
class SelectForm(forms.Form):
selection = forms.ChoiceField(
    choices=[
        (HumanModel, 'Human'),
        (OtherHumanModel, 'Other Human')
    ]
)
```

In my view:

```
def MyView(request):
    if request.method == "GET":

        form = SelectForm()
        return render(request, 'some-html', {
            "form": form
        })

    if request.method == "POST":
            data = request.POST['selection']
            #make a instance?
            return render(...)
```

and e.g in data is HumanModel, but in unicode
Is there possible to make instance of this model?
object = data(name="John")???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a Factory pattern for this. Use `HumanModel.__name__` to refer to the name of the class in the selection, than use the name in the Factory to create concrete instances of the class.

```
class SelectForm(forms.Form):
    selection = forms.ChoiceField(
    choices=[
        (HumanModel.__name__, 'Human'),
        (OtherHumanModel.__name__, 'Other Human')
    ]
)

class HumanModelFactory(object):
    def __init__(self, model_name):
        if model_name == "HumanModel":
            return HumanModel()
        if model_name == "OtherHumanModel":
            return OtherHumanModel()

# usage
model_name = request.POST['selection'] # e.g. 'HumanModel'
instance = HumanModelFactory(model_name)
```